# Error "psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied" at connect sublime text with postgres in JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, sublimetext3, postgresql-9.3

I try to query since sublime to my database but I can not send the password of DB.

sql.sublime-build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["psql", "-U","user", "-d","my_database" ,"-o","final.txt","-a", "-E", "-f","$file" ]
}
```

I tryed adding "-W","MyKey" or "-w" but not run

Comment: What should the command look like if run from the command line, and does it work if you do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html), you should use a `.pgpass` file, or if you must, the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable.

`-w` tells `psql` "never prompt for a password".

`-W` is "always prompt for a password".

There is no "here is the password" command line option.

Presumably sublime text offers a way to set environment variables on command invocations.

Another option, especially if on a development machine, is to tweak `pg_hba.conf` so no password is required for the connection in the first place. Again, see the documentation for details.